# Форматирование Ipv6

Tags: java, ipv6

Есть вот такой вот прекрасный метод

```
    public String ip6Address(NetworkInterface networkInterface) {
    String ip6 = String.valueOf(networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0).getAddress()).substring(1).split("%")[0];
    String mask = String.valueOf(networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0).getNetworkPrefixLength());
    String result = ip6 + "/" + mask;
    return result;
}
```

Возвращает он следующую строку fe80:0:0:0:bbee:b5a5:cc39:b141/64 или 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/128  - это IPv6 адрес и адрес localhost.

Вопрос заключается в следующем, как из этого:

fe80:0:0:0:bbee:b4a4:cc39:b141/64 сделать вот это fe80::bbee:b4a4:cc39:b141/64.

А из этого: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/128 сделать вот это ::1/128

То есть привести к нормальному виду без лишних нулей.

Документация [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html).

> Due to some methods of allocating certain styles of IPv6 addresses, it will be common for addresses to contain long strings of zero bits. In order to make writing addresses containing zero bits easier, a special syntax is available to compress the zeros. The use of "::" indicates multiple groups of 16-bits of zeros. The "::" can only appear once in an address. The "::" can also be used to compress the leading and/or trailing zeros in an address. For example, 1080::8:800:200C:417A

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3760936/1068283 (en)

Comment: Хорошее решение по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760936/java-library-for-converting-a-long-ipv6-address-into-its-compressed-form). Спасибо Michael Hampton